# How to bring Tensorboard curve to front?

Tags: tensorboard

If I have a lot of overlapping curves plotted in Tensorboard, sometimes the one that I want gets buried under the other curves. Is there a way to force the front-back ordering in which Tensorboard plots curves?

To be clear, I still want all of them showing, I just want to select one to be shown at the top.